# How to reduce the brightness of a desktop pc?

Tags: display

I can see the option to reduce the brightness of the screen on my laptop but not on my desktop. Is there a way to adjust this on my pc?

Answer (score 2):

Install graphics driver

> Settings > Additional drivers

Option to change brightness should be in settings:

> Settings > Brightness & Lock

Do you use latest version of elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Brightness Controller](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
```

For Version 1 with up to 4 Monitor Support:

```
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller-simple
```

[image: ]([![Brightness Controller Version 1]

For Version 2 with Multi Monitor Support and other features:

```
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

[image]
**Note:** This does not decrease the intensity of backlight, so won't save your batteries. But you can use this as a last resort to save your eyes.